# Not able to activate Virtual Environment in Python in Windows

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

I am using Windows and these are the steps i followed

1. created a folder by the name projectA
2. pip install virtualenv
3. cd projectA
4. python -m venv env01
5. now i can see a folder by the name env01
   Now my virtual environment is created, When i am trying to activate myb virtual environment, i am getting the following error
   [image]

This is my folder structure

[image]

I tried all the following commands, which is resulting in erorr

```
.\Scripts\activate
source venv/bin/activate
```

How to activate the Virtual Environment, pls help

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use Linux instructions in a Windows environment.

Comment: Shouldn't you use command like `source env01/bin/activate` ?

Comment: @PurushottamNawale, i get the error 'source' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet' when i use the above command

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk, what wud be the windows command to activate the virtual environment?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+source+is+not+recognized

Answer (score -2):

used the following command, it worked

```
{environment_folder}\Scripts\activate

env01\Scripts\activate
```

[refered the following blog](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/creating-python-virtual-environment-windows-linux/)